# Flipping a matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Real quick question:

I was wondering, how would one denote mathemathically the flipping of a matrix, horizontally or vertically, around its own axis?

Comment: I do not think that there is a common notation for this, since apart from the transposition $A^t$ any other 'flipping' isn't used very often. Can you provide some more information where you need this?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no convention about notations of these operations.

Comment: I don't think there's a standard notation. The operation that reflects across the diagonal, that is, replaces $(a_{ij})$ with $(a_{ji})$, is called the **transpose**, and is denoted $A \mapsto A^T$ or $A \mapsto A^t$..

Comment: You could use $A^H$ and $A^V$...

Comment: @flawr I need it to denote a horizontal flip of an image's grayscale values in matrix form.

Comment: Occasionally one wants to reorder the rows or columns of a matrix, which one might denote by the action $A \mapsto \sigma \cdot A$ of the appropriate permutation, but this certainly requires more explanation in context.

Comment: @Travis. In French notation, the transpose is traditionnally written as ${}^t\!\!A$ to avoid confusion with an exponent.

Comment: @V.Rossetto I suppose that also has the advantage that one can write the inverse transpose without ugly juxtaposition or parentheses, I may now be a convert...

Comment: @V.Rossetto ...which adds confucion for those who are not used to this: Consider $A^tB$: does this denote $A^t\cdot B$ or $A\cdot B^t$? Apart from that you can easily write $A^{-2t}$ etc. in non-french notation.

Comment: @flawr. I experienced the opposite confusion the first I read maths in English. Usually, a good spacing is enough to avoid the confusion you mention. Example $A\;{}^t\!B$.

Comment: Of course, I did not want to argue about what is the *better* notation, I just wanted to point out that IMHO you *can* mix the transposition sign with the exponent without loss of comprehensibility.

Comment: @flawr. You are right. It should only be clear that $A^{-1t}$ denotes the transpose of the inverse or the inverse of the transpose. In this example, ${}^t\!\!A^{-1}$ is not clear either.

Comment: But $(A^{-1})^t = (A^t)^{-1}$, so it does not matter? Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: @flawr. You are right. My last comment should have been written with ${}^h$ rather than with ${}^t$.

Comment: Ah ok this makes much more sense, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there is a general agreement that no such notation already exists. As I suggested in a comment you could use $A^H$ and $A^V$. If I was writing in a document in French, I would use ${}^h\!A$ and ${}^v\!A$.

Comment: Thanks for the precision for French. :) Do we (French people) really use different convetion for notation? Cause I didn't realize that and want to make sure I used internationnal ones.

Comment: @Deuteu. That is at least the notation I learned (long time ago). Note that I learned also to note combinations as $C_n^p$ and that now in French high school, everyone conformed to the international standard $\binom np$.

Comment: Ok cause I saw both notations (but indeed the ${}^h\!A$ kind in most of the case) and didn't realize that is because I was in France. But good to know.

Answer (score 10):

Let $P$ be the matrix with $1$ on the antidiagonal and $0$ otherwise, that is
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&\ldots& 0& 1\\0&0&\ldots & 1 & 0\\\vdots&\vdots &{}_.\cdot{}^\cdot&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&1&\ldots& 0& 0\\1&0&\ldots& 0& 0\\ \end{pmatrix}.$$ Then $AP$ and $PA$ (and $PAP$) are flipped versions of $A$.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, P in this case is called a permutation matrix and more generally is used to swap axis in matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but it is the first hit in search results for notation of flipping a matrix - so let's leave an answer.

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. If you use the notation that matrix $A = A_{ij}$ where $i \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$ represents the row and $j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ represents the column.

The following $7$ flips of $A$ come out of changing the indicies:

1. $A^\top = A_{ji}$

   - Transpose A by changing the order of the indices
2. $A_{i(n+1-j)}$.

   - Flip $A$ horizontally
   - This interchanges the columns so that the first column of $A$ is the last column of $A_{i(n+1-j)}$, and the last column of $A$ is the first column of $A_{i(n+1-j)}$.
3. $A_{(m+1-i)j}$

   - Flip $A$ vertically
   - This interchanges the rows so that the first row of $A$ is the last row of $A_{(m+1-i)j}$, and the last row of $A$ is the first row of $A_{(m+1-i)j}$.
4. $A_{(m+1-i)(n+1-j)}$

   - Flip $A$ horizontally then vertically
   - Same as flip vertical then horizontal
5. $A_{(n+1-j)i}$

   - Flip $A^\top$ vertically
6. $A_{j(m+1-i)}$

   - Flip $A^\top$ horizontally
7. $A_{(n+1-j)(m+1-i)}$

   - Flip $A^\top$ vertically then horizontally